# How to install printer properly

Tags: debian, cups, printer, brother

I have followed this [instructions](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloa%20%E2%80%A6%20&type3=625) to install my brother MFC-L2710DN driver. 
After installing the printer, I can see it in cups:

```
MFCL2710DN    MFCL2710DN        Brother MFCL2710DN for CUPS     Inactiva - "El archivo "/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_MFCL2710DN" tiene permisos no seguros (0100777/uid=0/gid=0)."
```

The owner of /usr/lib/cups/filter/ is root.
These are the printer settings:

```
Descripción:    MFCL2710DN
Ubicación:   
Controlador:    Brother MFCL2710DN for CUPS (escala de grises, dúplex)
Conexión:    dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L2710DN%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-3c2af4c53b80
Opciones predeterminadas:    rótulos=none, none papel=iso_a4_210x297mm caras=one-sided
```

If I go to printers on Debian 9, it shows this status: "The status of the printer is 'cups-insecure-filter'".

Errors are logged in this file [/var/log/cups/error_log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLtUQk%20%E2%80%A6%20sp=sharing)

If I execute the Debian troubleshoot, I get more information about the [error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13BqnzEMlybA-Onz4nHoN42cIdkyjK7Ag/view?usp=sharing)

Can somebody help me to install properly my printer machine?

Comment: Are you able to print to it? Have you run `cupsenable` and `cupsaccept` on the printer?

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_MFCL2710DN` like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456918/cups-insecure-filter-error-for-lexmark-printer-on-trusty) and restart cups. Btw., two of your links are already dead.